# How do I add a JavaFX MenuBar to a Swing FrameView?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, menubar, jmenubar

I've been trying to figure this out for a while to no avail. I have some code right now that takes a Swing JMenuBar and puts it into a FrameView with

```
FrameView v = new FrameView();
v.setMenuBar(jMenuBar.get());
```

I want to be able to do the same thing, but with a JavaFX MenuBar now that the menus have been converted. Is this possible? Or do I have to wait for the entire application to be converted to FX before adding in the new menus? I'm looking for something like this:

```
FrameView v = new FrameView();
v.setMenuBar(menuBarFX.get());
```

Comment: `FrameView` What the huh? I don't know of any such class in either Swing or Java-FX. Link to the Java Docs for this class.

Comment: I can't seem to find one, but it's org.jdesktop.application.FrameView. It returns a JFrame.

Comment: It's part of the (long abandoned AFAIU) Swing Application Framework. Java Docs are [`org.jdesktop.application.FrameView`](http://javadox.com/net.java.dev.appframework/appframework/1.03/org/jdesktop/application/FrameView.html)

Comment: You could just wrap a JavaFX `MenuBar` in a [`JFXPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html). Though be aware you will have threading issues to work with if you mix JavaFX and Swing.